# How to install a private key (.pfx certificate) on android?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, tablet, pdf, certificates

I want to read a protected pdf file. I installed in on my Windows PC and install the .pfx certificate with the password to read it. There I can open it normally. But I can't do the same on my android tablet. When I install it, doesn't seem to be working. It doesn't even show up in the certificate list on the system settings.

Isn't there anyway to do the same on my Android tablet? To open it normally?